# Most efficient way to take previous 70 values from an array and put them into a new dimension

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array

To be more precise, I'll give an example, I currently have a 3D matrix of dimensions 375 x 1226 x 64.
What I need to do is change the last dimension so that instead of 375 x 1226 x 64 I have 375 x 1226 x 70 x 64, where those 70 x 64 values are taken from the previous 70 values.

I implemented this, but unfortunately it takes too much time:

```
    for i in range(0, old_mat.shape[0]):
        for j in range(0, old_mat.shape[1]):
            stop = j - 70 + 1
            if stop < 0:
                stop = 0
            temp = old_mat[i:i + 1, stop: j + 1].squeeze(0)
            new_mat[i][j][:temp.shape[0]] = temp
```

Edit:
let's say a 2d (3 x 4) array:

```
[[1, 2, 5, 6], [2, 3, 3, 6], [3, 4, 5, 7]]
```

Now instead of 70, let's say we need about 3.
The output would then be a 3d (3 x 3 x 4):

```
[
 [[1,2,5,6],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0]],
 [[2,3,3,6],[1,2,5,6],[0,0,0,0]],
 [[3,4,5,7],[2,3,3,6],[1,2,5,6]]
]
```

Comment: But your last dimension only has 64 values?

Comment: Yes, it always has 64 values

Comment: Why do you want a new array that is 70 times larger?

Comment: Make a much smaller example, one where you can show both inputs and result.  It's hard to make sense of your code.  It may run, but I'm not sure the result is sensible.

Comment: Ok, i'll try to make another example

Answer (score 0):

```
In [61]: arr = np.array([[1, 2, 5, 6], [2, 3, 3, 6], [3, 4, 5, 7]])                            
In [62]: arr1 = np.zeros((arr.shape[0],3,arr.shape[-1]),int)
```

It's enough to iterate on the first dimension, and copy slices:

```
In [64]: for i in range(arr.shape[0]): 
    ...:     arr1[i,i:,:] = arr[:(3-i),:] 
    ...:                                                                                       
In [65]: arr1                                                                                  
Out[65]: 
array([[[1, 2, 5, 6],
        [2, 3, 3, 6],
        [3, 4, 5, 7]],

       [[0, 0, 0, 0],
        [1, 2, 5, 6],
        [2, 3, 3, 6]],

       [[0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0],
        [1, 2, 5, 6]]])
```